# Swift How to pan UIImage in UiImageView?

Tags: swift3, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a simple test application and I want to pan an image inside its view. It will not pan or zoom and I can't see what's wrong with my code.

I have followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQ7MgJX_L6k) tutorial but implemented it in code. I've made the image width the same as the height so I can pan without necessarily zooming.

Here is my code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        return scrollView
    }()

    let zoomImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "lighthouse")
        return imageView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white 

        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height

        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: screenHeight, height: screenHeight)
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0

        zoomImageView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: screenHeight, height: screenHeight)

        scrollView.addSubview(self.zoomImageView)

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return zoomImageView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search in your code for the term `contentSize`. You don't see it, do you? But the most fundamental fact about how a scroll view works is this: a scroll view without a `contentSize` *cannot scroll* (i.e. "pan" as you put it). In particular, it must have a content size larger than its own bounds size in order to be able to scroll along that axis (height or width, or both). Otherwise, there is nothing to scroll.

Comment: This isn't mentioned in the tutorial I linked to. How did he achieve it?

Comment: Assuming I have a square image and I want to fill the full height of the view, what size should I make the scrollview and content so I can scroll my picture horizontally?

Comment: Thanks, I changed the scroll view width to screen width and the content size to screen height square.

Comment: Glad it worked out! You might want to read up on how a scroll view works: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html

Comment: My only problem now is I can't scroll right. The image is centered but I can only scroll left to reveal the ride side of my image. If I drag it right I can see the left side but it springs back to the center.

Comment: If the scroll view's content size width is not as large as the image view width, you can't scroll the image sideways.